# Generic decorator inspired by functional programming

Tags: c++, design-patterns, c++20

I made a generic decorator in C++20 with concept for specialization. The idea is to be able to define only one function in the decorator to decorate all functions in a class.

You may [try it](https://godbolt.org/z/96ss7beGa) (it's a bit long to insert here and it's better to see it work). Please, read it at the same time while reading this post.

This decorator is inspired by functional programming:

There is two kind of functions : `getter` that return a value and don't modify the object and `setter` that returns a modified copy of the object.

This decorator heavily uses template. To call the `A` getter function, I need to call the function of the class decorating the root class:

`classe->f<F::Get, F::A>()`

The `f` function name must be used to be specialized by decorator. All functions decorated are `f`.

The first argument in template is to tell if I want to get a value (and just return the value) or if I want to set a value (and return a modified clone of the object).

The second argument is the name of the function. **The bad thing** is that I need an enum with all possible name of functions, which is bad.

I split the `get` and the name of the function on purpose. So, I can access multiple level of component (`classe->f<F::Get, F::A, F::B>()`). I know this could be considered bad in programming but I want to avoid boilerplate code.

Questions are:

- how can I get rid of the huge enum that has all possible names of functions ?
- do you have an idea to improve the style ? `classe->f<F::Get, F::A>()` must be used everywhere and it's really different than a classic `classe->a()`. On the other hand, the `f` function is the only way to tell "please, decorate me".
- if I want to decorate a class that don't respect the `f` style, I need to write a glue to convert all functions I want to decorate to a `f` function. How can I avoid doing that ?

I tried to be descriptive but I can expand/improve my explanation.

**Update**: insertion of the code in the question

**Update 2**: why a Start/End Decorator ? I need nested decorator.

I want to split features. I.e., I want to be able to print the duration of a function, log activity in a file and send telemetry to a server. I could do it with this style (it's long but it's understandable) :

```
using Decorator = DecoratorStart<PrintDuration<LogAccess<SendTelemetry<DecoratorEnd<ClassTest>>>>>
```

If I want to remove a feature, I just have to change this line.

Why `DecoratorStart` ? It stores as `shared_ptr` the instantiation of the class I want to decorate. I can't store the instantiation in decorator either I will need to clone them if I clone an object.

Why `DecoratorEnd` ? To know where is the end of the decorator in the template.

I read that people uses `Decorator1<Decorator2<Decorator3<Class, Class>, Class>, Class>` and I wanted to avoid it. At first I tried to extract the last class of a nested template but it may fails with `Decorator<Class<int>>` where `Class` will be guessed as Decorator.

Finally, I need to instantiate the class in `DecoratorEnd` because it's the only class that knows the root type. All other decorators only know the type of the child decorator.

## Source code

```
#include <memory>

// For log decorator
#include <spdlog/sinks/stdout_sinks.h>
#include <spdlog/spdlog.h>

// List of all functions
enum class F
{
  // Getter, Setter and Clone is mandatory
  Get,
  Set,
  Clone,

  // Functions implemented by class that can be decorated.
  Func
};

/// Start of the header for decorator.

// Helpers

// Tell if value in template is the same.
// Example:
// template<bool T>
// requires Equals<bool, true, T>
// void f(){}
template <typename T, T V1, T V2>
concept Equals = std::is_same_v<std::integral_constant<T, V1>,
                                std::integral_constant<T, V2>>;


// The start decorator stores the class decorated
// in field impl_ and stores the first decorator
// in field deco_.
template <typename T>
class DecoratorStart final
{
 public:
  template <typename... Args>
  explicit DecoratorStart(Args&&... args)
      : deco_(std::make_shared<T>(impl_, std::forward<Args>(args)...))
  {
  }
  DecoratorStart(const DecoratorStart&) = default;
  DecoratorStart(DecoratorStart&&) = delete;
  DecoratorStart& operator=(const DecoratorStart&) = delete;
  DecoratorStart& operator=(DecoratorStart&&) = delete;

  ~DecoratorStart() = default;

  // General form.
  // F must be Get or Set.
  template <F Action, F... U, typename... Args>
  [[nodiscard]] auto f(const Args&&... args) const
  {
    // Setter always return a modified copy of the class.
    // Inspired by functional style. 
    if constexpr (Action == F::Set)
    {
      auto retval = f<F::Set, F::Clone>();
      retval->impl_ = deco_->template f<Action, U...>(
          *impl_, std::forward<const Args>(args)...);
      return retval;
    }
    // Getter simply returns a value.
    else
    {
      return deco_->template f<Action, U...>(*impl_,
                                             std::forward<const Args>(args)...);
    }
  }

  // Specialization with concept if F is Set and function is Clone.
  template <F Action, F U>
  requires Equals<F, Action, F::Set> && Equals<F, U, F::Clone>
  [[nodiscard]] std::shared_ptr<DecoratorStart<T>> f() const
  {
    return std::make_shared<DecoratorStart<T>>(*this);
  }

 private:
  std::shared_ptr<typename T::RootType> impl_;
  std::shared_ptr<T> deco_;
};

// The end decorator stores the type of the class
// decorated and call the final function.
template <typename T>
class DecoratorEnd
{
 public:
  using RootType = T;

  template <typename... Args>
  explicit DecoratorEnd(std::shared_ptr<T>& impl, Args&&... args)
  {
    impl = std::make_shared<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }
  DecoratorEnd(const DecoratorEnd&) = default;
  DecoratorEnd(DecoratorEnd&&) = delete;
  DecoratorEnd& operator=(const DecoratorEnd&) = delete;
  DecoratorEnd& operator=(DecoratorEnd&&) = delete;

  ~DecoratorEnd() = default;

  template <F Action, F... U, typename... Args>
  [[nodiscard]] auto f(const T& classe, const Args&&... args) const
  {
    return classe.template f<Action, U...>(std::forward<const Args>(args)...);
  }
};

/// End of the header for decorator.

// Example of decorator with parameter in constructor.
template <typename T>
class LogDuration
{
 public:
  using RootType = typename T::RootType;

  template <typename... Args>
  LogDuration(std::shared_ptr<RootType>& impl,
              std::shared_ptr<spdlog::logger> log,
              // Need args if more constructor decorator needs argument.
              Args&&... args)
      : t(impl, std::forward<Args>(args)...), log_(std::move(log))
  {
  }
  LogDuration(const LogDuration&) = default;
  LogDuration(LogDuration&&) = delete;
  LogDuration& operator=(const LogDuration&) = delete;
  LogDuration& operator=(LogDuration&&) = delete;

  ~LogDuration() = default;

  // No specialization. Hit all functions.
  template <F Action, F... U, typename... Args>
  [[nodiscard]] auto f(const RootType& classe, const Args&&... args) const
  {
    const auto t_start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto retval =
        t.template f<Action, U...>(classe, std::forward<const Args>(args)...);
    const auto t_end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    const double elapsed_time_ms =
        std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>(t_end - t_start).count();
    log_->info("duration " + std::to_string(elapsed_time_ms) + " ms");
    return retval;
  }

 private:
  T t;

  std::shared_ptr<spdlog::logger> log_;
};

/// End of the header for decorator.

// Example of class that can be decorated.
class ClassTest final
{
 public:
  ClassTest() = default;
  ClassTest(const ClassTest&) = default;
  ClassTest(ClassTest&&) = delete;
  ClassTest& operator=(const ClassTest&) = delete;
  ClassTest& operator=(ClassTest&&) = delete;

  ~ClassTest() = default;

  // Clone is mandatory for setter.
  template <F Action, F T>
  requires Equals<F, Action, F::Set> && Equals<F, T, F::Clone>
  [[nodiscard]] std::shared_ptr<ClassTest> f() const
  {
    return std::make_shared<ClassTest>(*this);
  }

  // Getter
  template <F Action, F T>
  requires Equals<F, Action, F::Get> && Equals<F, T, F::Func>
  [[nodiscard]] double f() const { return b_; }

  // Setter
  template <F Action, F T>
  requires Equals<F, Action, F::Set> && Equals<F, T, F::Func>
  [[nodiscard]] std::shared_ptr<ClassTest> f(const double b) const
  {
    auto retval = f<F::Set, F::Clone>();
    retval->b_ = b;
    return retval;
  }

 private:
  double b_ = std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN();
};

int main()
{
  spdlog::stdout_logger_mt("log");
  auto log = spdlog::get("log");

  using Decorator =
      DecoratorStart<LogDuration<DecoratorEnd<ClassTest>>>;
  const auto classe = std::make_shared<Decorator>(log);
  const auto classe2 = classe->f<F::Set, F::Func>(10.);
  assert((classe2->f<F::Get, F::Func>()) == 10.);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @G.Sliepen I just insert the code in the question. Source code of godbolt link are immutable but I understand the need to insert the code in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Answers to your questions

> - How can I get rid of the huge `enum` that has all possible names of functions?

Instead of putting everything in one `enum`, you can just have an arbitrary number of types. Instead of checking the value of the `enum`, you check whether the right type has been passed as a template argument. This can be done in several ways, either create multiple overloads, or have a single one that accepts arbitrary types and use `if constexpr` as you already did, but now to check whether the type matches:

```
namespace F {
    class Get{};
    class Set{};
    ...
};

template <typename Action>
auto f(...) {
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<Action, F::Get) {
        /* getter code */
    } else {
        /* setter code */
    }
}
```

Alternatively, instead of using the action types as template parameters, you can use tag dispatch:

```
auto f(F::Get, ...) {
    /* getter code */
}

auto f(F::Set, ...) {
    /* setter code */
}
```

And then call the latter with default constructed action objects like so:

```
ClassTest test;
test.f(F::Set{}, 10.);
assert(test.f(F::Get{}) == 10.);
```

> - Do you have an idea to improve the style? `classe->f<F::Get, F::A>()` must be used everywhere and it's really different than a classic `classe->a()`. On the other hand, the `f` function is the only way to tell "please, decorate me".

You can't in C++, unless you explicitly provide a member function `a()` in your decorators as well. You can't automatically create member functions in a class based on what is in another class at the moment, it might be possible in some future C++ version.

However, the next best thing might be to add an `operator()` to those action types, that take a reference to the object you want the action to be performed on:

```
namespace F {
    class Get {
    public:
        template<typename T, typename... Args>
        auto operator(T& t, Args&&... args) {
            return t.get(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        }
    };
    ...
}
```

Then you could use it like so:

```
ClassTest test; // assuming it has get() and set() member functions
F::Set{}(test, 10.);
assert(F::Get{}(test) == 10.);
```

> - If I want to decorate a class that don't respect the `f` style, I need to write a glue to convert all functions I want to decorate to a `f` function. How can I avoid doing that?

Again, you can't, at least not in standard C++ at this moment. However, with the above you could make the decorator "`f` style" but let the class you want to decorate have multiple member functions. The decorator class would then look like:

```
template<typename T>
class Decorator {
    Decorator(T& t, ...) t(t) {...}

    template<typename Action, typename... Args>
    auto f(Action action, Args&&... args) {
        /* do some stuff */
        ...

        /* call the original function */
        return action(t, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
private:
    T& t;
}
```

So that this works:

```
Decorator<ClassTest> test;
test.f(F::Set{}, 10.); // calls test.t.set(10.);
```

## It is way more complicated than necessary

The way to create a decorated class looks very complicated. Since `LogDuration` already knows it is a decorator, what benefit is there to add the `DecoratorStart` and `DecoratorEnd` classes? Assuming we keep using a template argument of type `enum class F` to select which function to dispatch, it could look like this:

```
template <typename T>
class LogDuration {
public:
  template <typename... Args>
  LogDuration(Args&&... args): t(args...) {}
  ...

  template <F Action, typename... Args>
  auto f(Args&&... args) {
    const auto t_start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto retval = t.template f<Action>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    const auto t_end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    const double elapsed_time_ms =
        std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>(t_end - t_start).count();
    std::clog << "duration " << elapsed_time_ms << " ms\n";
    return retval;
  }

private:
  T t;
};

class ClassTest {
public:
  ...

  template <F Action>
  requires (Action == F::Get)
  double f() { return b_; }

  template <F Action>
  requires (Action == F::Set)
  double f(double b) { return b_ = b; }

private:
  double b_;
};
```

And then it can be used like so:

```
LogDuration<ClassTest> foo;
foo.f<F::Set>(10.);
assert(foo.f<F::Get>() == 10.);
```

Note that the above avoided using any `std::shared_ptr`s. I've omitted `const`-versions of everything, and you also need to do some work to handle `f()` returning `void`.

Comment: Many thanks for your review. It's a good idea to use a class instead of an enum. I already thought about this way but I can't remember why I didn't used it. I like to put it in the template arguments. If I pass it as argument of the function, I'm scared that the compiler will instantiate the class instead of using the class just as signature's function.

Comment: I'm not really fan of the F::get(test, args...). I would like to stay as closed as possible to a classic C++ coding style.

Comment: Finally, there is one thing I forgot to mention. I build my decorator to handle nested decorator. For example, I can use `DecoratorStart<LogDuration<LogDuration<DecoratorEnd<ClassTest>>>>`. This is why I needed to have a Start and a End decorator. I will update my question according this.

Comment: An empty class doesn't cost anything to instantiate. I tried `DecoratorStart<LogDuration<LogDuration<DecoratorEnd<ClassTest>>>>` with your code, but it fails to compile.

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit optimistic. You also need to change the instantiation `std::make_shared<Decorator>(log, log);`. `LogDuration` needs to have the log as argument in the constructor. So if you have two `LogDuration`, you need to pass `log` twice.

Comment: I'm using `shared_ptr` everywhere because every `set` needs to duplicate. I think the only `share_ptr` I should remove is the instantiation of the decorator in the `main` function.